# Matlab WDM: ??? Error using ==> save [save_network]

Tags: matlab, networking, wdm

I hope this finds you well. Actually, I've been reading through the file create_network.m from matlab tool WDM and I'm trying to create a network but I always get the same error. Here are the steps I follow and the error.

PS: I tried this also with name: 'mesh.mat' after loading the mesh.mat to working memory. I tried other names as well but I always get the same problem.

> > create_network(9,'mesh')
> >     Does network have wages (y/n): n

Please give incident nodes with node 1: 2 4

Please give incident nodes with node 2: 1 3 5

Please give incident nodes with node 3: 2 6

Please give incident nodes with node 4: 1 5 7

Please give incident nodes with node 5: 2 6 8 4

Please give incident nodes with node 6: 3 5 9

Please give incident nodes with node 7: 4 8

Please give incident nodes with node 8: 7 5 9

Please give incident nodes with node 9: 8 6

??? Error using ==> save
Unable to write file mesh: permission denied.

Error in ==> create_network>save_network at 161
save(name,'description','structure');

Error in ==> create_network at 97
    varargout{1}=save_network(description,structure,varargin{2});

Would you please guide me solve this problem?

Thanks infinitely,

Comment: You do not have write permissions in the directory where you're trying to save. what does `pwd` return?

Comment: it gives: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\work\networks

Comment: Have you considered moving the WDM toolbox somewhere into another folder but outside the $matlabroot$ where you have write permissions?

Comment: Hi @OlegKomarov :) I solved the issue. It was because I forgot to change the path in create_network.mat file. Now it's working perfectly